# Coloring specified character of string in java

Tags: java, android, character, text-coloring

I'm trying to do an coloring of specified character of an input string. Input string load from database. The problem is : how to coloring of specified character like this one? : [image]

So, every character "mp" is red color. And how to scan if there is "mp" character? Text is dynamic from database. Not always like above.  I want to every "mp" character is red color. Not only in "simple" text, but also every text that contain "mp" character. if there is, then color that character to red color.
I'm using java Android programming.

Thanks.

Comment: how about scan if there is "mp" character? Text is dynamics from database. Not always like above.

Comment: Ruchira : it's different, i want to scan text, is there "mp" character? if there is, then color that character to red color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("mp");  // insert your pattern here
Matcher m = p.matcher("Simple Text, bumping , jumping");
while (m.find()) {
   positions.add(m.start());
}

// interate this for position times 
Spannable spanning = new SpannableString("Simple Text");        

spanning.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),positions.get(i), positions.get(i)+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textview.setText(spanning);
```

Comment: how about scan if there is "mp" character? Text is dynamics from database. Not always like above

Comment: u can use index of function

Comment: but, if there is text "bumping", code above is not work. Help me. I want to every "mp" character is red color. Not only in "simple" text, but also every text that contain "mp" character.

Comment: u need to highlight only Simple?

Comment: no, Not only in "simple" text, but also every text that contain "mp" character

Comment: hey checkout my edit i got ur doubt...did u got output for bumping?